# Encode URL path and show it in browser

Tags: html, django, url, get, encode

I use django to build a blog website. I use the python urllib.quote function to encode the url string without submitt a form. For example, in my html file, there has href link like this:

```
http://example.com/post/?tag=new%20tag  (1)
```

(1) is the link I encoded from (2):

```
  http://example.com/post/?tag=new tag  (2)
```

This is a little different from the form GET method, where "new tag" is encoded as "new+tag". Both are fine with me as long as the output url contains no space.

However, after I click link (1) in my webpage, the resulting url in the browser looks like the link (2) (with space).Should I just leave my link as (2)? How can I make the output url to be (1) or maybe the following standard one:

```
 http://example.com/post/?tag=new+tag  (3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `urlencode`:

```
 >>> import urllib
 >>> urllib.urlencode({'tag': 'new tag'})
'tag=new+tag'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You should instead use `urllib.quote_plus` to round trip the encoding.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus